# Product Page not updating in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento, caching, refresh, product, reindex

I've tried everything I can find on the web about Magento 1.9 and refreshing a product page.  I've updated the price and the old price is still displayed.

Things I've tried:
 - Hard refresh in browser
 - Different browser
 - Private browsing

- I've refreshed the cache for all caches in the page "Cache Storage Management"
- The  Magento Cache has been flushed
- The Cache Storage has been flushed
- All indexes have been reindexed
- Disable and re-enable combining CSS and JavaScript files.

I'm on the correct product page.  Both the URL and the product ID match the page and the product in magento.

I've deleted all files in the "/var/cache" folder.

I've updated the product description by adding a period and other small stuff.

Yet the page stays the same. Every time I refresh it displays the old data.

What else can I try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The web host implemented server side caching.  Disabling their caching was the solution that worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to fix it by do the re-indexing of "Product Prices". like below:

```
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_price
```

Comment: The issue was with server side caching implemented by the host.